# How to sort text column that has mostly numbers and a dot

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access , I have a field by name "TargetDays" that has values like `"0", "13", 20", "6", "1", "9", ".""2", "28"`

I want them to be sorted as

```
., 0, 1, 2, 6, 9, 13, 20, 28
```

I tried doing `ORDER BY val(TargetDays)`
But this sorts sometimes as `., 0, 1, 2, 6, 13, 20, 28`. But other times it sorts as `0, ., 1, 2, 6, 13, 20, 28`. The problem is coming with `"." and "0"`.

Could someone please tell me a solution to sort in the intended order (as mentioned above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `Val(".")` and `Val("0")` both return 0, so your `ORDER BY` has no way to distinguish between those 2 characters in your `[TargetDays]` field ... and no way to know it should sort *"."* before *"0"*.

You can include a secondary sort, based on ASCII values, to tell it what you want.  An Immediate window example of the `Asc()` function in action ...

```
? Asc("."), Asc("0")
 46            48
```

You could base your secondary sort on that function ...

```
ORDER BY val(TargetDays), Asc(TargetDays)
```

However, I don't think you should actually need to include the function because this should give you the same result ...

```
ORDER BY val(TargetDays), TargetDays
```

Comment: Thank you so very much @HansUp